# How to add additional times to my counter?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a countdown clock that goes from one date to the next. An example would be a count down to Halloween then to Thanksgiving. When the countdown reaches zero, I want the counter to restart and count down to the next holiday.

I've tried separating the events and labeling them differently to target them independently. ANy ideas would be great, this has me stuck.

```
<div class="container">
    <p  id="timer">
   <span  id="timer-days"></span>
    <span  id="timer-hours"></span>
    <span  id="timer-minutes"></span>
    <span  id="timer-seconds"></span>
</p>
</div>

<script>

var holidazeEnd=new Date("Jun, 9 2019 18:19:00").getTime();
var holidazeEnd1=new Date("Jun, 9 2019 18:20:00").getTime();

var timer= setInterval(function(){

let now=new Date().getTime();
let t=holidazeEnd - now;



if (t >= 0)
 {

    let days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let mins = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let secs = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("timer-days").innerHTML=days+"<span class= 'label'> Days</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-hours").innerHTML=("0"+hours).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Hours</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-minutes").innerHTML=("0"+mins).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Minutes</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-seconds").innerHTML=("0"+secs).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Seconds</span>";

}
     else{
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHtml=("Happy Independence Day!");}
},1000)
//---------------------------------------------//


var timer1= setInterval(function(){

let now=new Date().getTime();
let t=holidazeEnd1 - now;

if (t >= 0) {

    let days1 = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours1 = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let mins1 = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let secs1 = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("timer-days").innerHTML=days1+"<span class= 'label'> Days</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-hours").innerHTML=("0"+hours1).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Hours</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-minutes").innerHTML=("0"+mins1).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Minutes</span>";


    document.getElementById("timer-seconds").innerHTML=("0"+secs1).slice(-2)+"<span class= 'label'> Seconds</span>";

}
     else
    document.getElementById("timer1").innerHtml="Merry Xmas!";}
,1000);

countdown(holidazeEnd,timer);

countdown(holidazeEnd1,timer1)
```

Comment: Please explain what your problem is.

Comment: The problme is that the timer is not restarting after it reaches 0. I would like the counter to restart and countdown to the next hoilday.

Comment: `new Date("Jun, 9 2019 18:19:00")` is not a good idea. `new Date(2019,5,9,18,19,0)` is much preferred.

Comment: Your problem is that you are starting two timers that start more or less at the same time and write to the same elements. You need an approach similar to that suggested by filipe, where you have one timer that uses an array of dates to count down too. Once it's completed one date, it can start on the next one.

Comment: @All I made some changes in my answer, and even added some features, I hope you'll like them

Answer (score 1):

What about to use a single setInterval and an array of holidays?

```
    const holidays = [
        {
            running: "Independence Day",
            complete: "Happy Independence Day!",
            time: "July 4 2019"
        },
        {
            running: "Christmas",
            complete: "Merry Xmas!",
            time: "Dec 10 2019"
        }
    ];
```

We need to know the next holiday to track:

```
    //Get the next holiday index
    const nextHolidayIndex = () => holidays.reduce((prevResult,current, i) => {

        const timeDif = Date.parse(current.time) - Date.now();

        if(timeDif < 0)
            return prevResult;

        if(prevResult.index == -1 || timeDif <  prevResult.diff) return {
            index : i,
            diff: timeDif
        };

        return prevResult;

    }, {index : -1, diff: 0}).index;
```

The time remaining, like you did:

```
    //Get time remaining for a given time
    const getTimeRemaining = (timeTime) =>{
        const t = Date.parse(timeTime) - Date.now();
        const seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        const minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        const hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        const days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }
```

And we need to initialize the component:

```
    const initializeClock = (id, nextHoliday) => {
        const clock = document.getElementById(id);
        const message = clock.querySelector('.message');
        const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
        let interval

        function updateClock() {
            const t = getTimeRemaining(nextHoliday.time);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days.toString();
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                message.innerHTML = nextHoliday.complete
            }
        }
        message.innerHTML = `${nextHoliday.running}`
        updateClock();
        interval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
```

How about the html ?

```
<div id="timer">
    <h1 class="message"></h1>
    <div class="countdown">
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Putting some visual to it:

```
    #timer{
        text-align: center;
        background: #efefef;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 24px;
    }

    h1{
        color: #969696;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }

    #timer .countdown{
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    #timer .countdown > div{
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #6f7b75;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #timer .countdown div > span{
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #03A9F4;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .smalltext{
        padding-top: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Then we just run the code:

```
    const next = nextHolidayIndex()
    if(next != -1){
        initializeClock('timer', holidays[next]);
    }
```

Here you go :)

```js
   const holidays = [
        {
            running: "Independence Day",
            complete: "Happy Independence Day!",
            time: "July 4 2019"
        },
        {
            running: "Christmas",
            complete: "Merry Xmas!",
            time: "Dec 10 2019"
        }
    ];

    //Get the next holiday index
    const nextHolidayIndex = () => holidays.reduce((prevResult,current, i) => {

        const timeDif = Date.parse(current.time) - Date.now();

        if(timeDif < 0)
            return prevResult;

        if(prevResult.index == -1 || timeDif <  prevResult.diff) return {
            index : i,
            diff: timeDif
        };

        return prevResult;

    }, {index : -1, diff: 0}).index;

    //Get time remaining for a given time
    const getTimeRemaining = (timeTime) =>{
        const t = Date.parse(timeTime) - Date.now();
        const seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        const minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        const hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        const days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    const initializeClock = (id, nextHoliday) => {
        const clock = document.getElementById(id);
        const message = clock.querySelector('.message');
        const daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        const hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        const minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        const secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
        let interval

        function updateClock() {
            const t = getTimeRemaining(nextHoliday.time);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days.toString();
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                message.innerHTML = nextHoliday.complete
                startNext()
            }
        }
        message.innerHTML = `${nextHoliday.running}`
        updateClock();
        interval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    const startNext = () => {
        const next = nextHolidayIndex()
        if(next != -1){
            initializeClock('timer', holidays[next]);
        }
    }

    startNext()
```

```css
    #timer{
        text-align: center;
        background: #efefef;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 24px;
    }

    h1{
        color: #969696;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }

    #timer .countdown{
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    #timer .countdown > div{
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #6f7b75;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #timer .countdown div > span{
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background: #03A9F4;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .smalltext{
        padding-top: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="timer">
    <h1 class="message"></h1>
    <div class="countdown">
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to restart the counter we need to refresh the page. If you don't want it then, forget about the message, and just init the next after the previous reach 0.

```
 const initializeClock = (id, nextHoliday) => {
        //...
        if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                startNext()
            }
        //...
    }

 const startNext = () => {
        const next = nextHolidayIndex()
        if(next != -1){
            initializeClock('timer', holidays[next]);
        }
    }

 startNext()
```

Comment: It's  working only for 2019, not for 2020 and all next years

Comment: Op did not ask for it. The json array can be generated taking in consideration if the event is in past, set the year 1 time in future, but there are holidays that aren't always in the same day every year.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example goes around the question:
 - you can add as many dates as you want,
 - adjust the end date of their presentation before moving on to the next countdown.

I do some changing for cosmetic reasons...

```js
// Set all the dates you want (no order needed)
const holidays = [
  { dat: 'July, 3 YYYY 23:59:59', end: 'July, 4 YYYY 23:59:59', msg:'Happy Independence Day!', bef:'Independence Day', Bcolor : '#39CCCC' }
, { dat: 'Dec, 24 YYYY 23:59:59', end: 'Dec, 26 YYYY 12:00:00', msg:'Merry Xmas!',             bef:'Xmas',             Bcolor : '#2ECC40' }
, { dat: 'Oct, 31 YYYY 17:59:59', end: 'Nov, 1 YYYY 06:00:00',  msg:'Happy Halloween!',        bef:'Halloween',        Bcolor : '#F012BE' }
, { dat: 'Dec, 31 YYYY 23:59:59', end: 'Jan, 1 Y+1Y 01:00:00',  msg:'Happy New Year!',         bef:'New Year',         Bcolor : '#FFDC00' }
];
// please note the use of 'YYYY' stand for 'any Year' and 'Y+1Y' stand fort 'any Following Year' for events repeating each year.
// Real year values are ok but old events will be ignored
// The color is here for example, you can disable it or change the idea by placing a picture in the background, 
// and do the same countdown for each species

// Ready for everything:
const BODY_color = '#554a63'   // standard Color of Background
,     timer_on   = document.querySelector('#timer-on')
,     timer_off  = document.querySelector('#timer-off')
,     curDT      = document.getElementById('currentDateTime')
,     tCountDown = document.querySelectorAll('#countdown div span')
,     xDays      = 0
,     xHours     = 2
,     xMins      = 4
,     xSecs      = 6
,     t_msg      = document.querySelector('#timer-on h2')
,     H_message  = document.querySelector('#timer-off h1')
,     one_Sec    = 1000
,     one_Min    = one_Sec * 60
,     one_Hour   = one_Min * 60 
,     one_Day    = one_Hour * 24
,     Option_DT  = { weekday: 'long', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}
,     Intl_F_DT  = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', Option_DT )
;

/* Search function to set the countDown target

 do : set interface to correct closest countdown
      even if it is during a period before ending event

 return : (js object )
    start    : time target of event
    ending   : time target of event ending
    complete : Boolean value (set to false) according to the countdown is not completed
    Bcolor   : paint color value for background during ending period
*/
function SetNextHolidayTarget()
{
  let now      = new Date()
  ,   nowTime  = now.getTime()
  ,   thisYear = now.getFullYear()
  ,   closest  = one_Day *365      /// start with big closest date
  ,   target   = null
  ;
  // default display
  timer_on.classList.remove('noDisplay')
  timer_off.classList.add('noDisplay')
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = BODY_color;

  holidays.forEach(H=>  // search loop for the closest date in 'holidays'
  {
    let s_date = H.dat.replace('YYYY', thisYear )            // change 'YYYY' string to current year value
    ,   e_date = H.end.replace('YYYY', thisYear ).replace('Y+1Y', (thisYear +1) )
    ,   t_date = new Date(s_date)  // target date  
    ,   z_date = new Date(e_date)  // target date ending
    ;
    if ( t_date < now && z_date < now ) // if target date and ending are before today, this set them for next year
    {
      s_date = H.dat.replace('YYYY', (thisYear +1))
      e_date = H.end.replace('YYYY', (thisYear +1)).replace('Y+1Y', (thisYear +2) )
      t_date = new Date(s_date)
      z_date = new Date(e_date) 
    }

    let t_datesDiff = t_date.getTime() - nowTime
    ,   z_datesDiff = z_date.getTime() - nowTime

    if ( closest > t_datesDiff && t_datesDiff > 0 )  // if it is closer than the dates already seen
    {
      closest               = t_datesDiff
      t_msg.textContent     = H.bef
      H_message.textContent = H.msg
      target                = { start: t_date.getTime(), ending: z_date.getTime(), complete: false, Bcolor: H.Bcolor }
    }

    if ( closest > z_datesDiff && z_datesDiff > 0 )  // case of inside countdown period
    {
      closest               = z_datesDiff
      t_msg.textContent     = H.bef
      H_message.textContent = H.msg
      target                = { start: z_date.getTime(), ending: z_date.getTime(), complete: true, Bcolor: H.Bcolor }
    }
  })

  if ( target.complete ) // if inside countdown period
  {
    timer_on.classList.add('noDisplay')
    timer_off.classList.remove('noDisplay')
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = target.Bcolor;
  }

  return target
}

// **** INIT ****
var holidazeEnd =  SetNextHolidayTarget()

// first TEST to prove -------------------------------------------------------------------
if (true)                 // (set to false to remove this test)
{
  let now    = new Date() 
  ,   start  = new Date()
  ,   ending = new Date()
  ;

  // default display
  timer_on.classList.remove('noDisplay')
  timer_off.classList.add('noDisplay')
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = BODY_color;

  start.setTime(now.getTime() + (one_Sec *20) );
  ending.setTime(start.getTime() + (one_Sec *15) );

  t_msg.textContent     = 'Test to 20s'
  H_message.textContent = 'happy test ! (15s)'

  holidazeEnd = { start , ending , complete: false, Bcolor: 'orange' }
} // =====================================================================================

//  TIMER Interval //
// - - - - - - - - //
var timerInterval = setInterval(function ()
{
  let now = new Date()
  ,   t   = holidazeEnd.start - now.getTime()
  ;
  curDT.textContent = Intl_F_DT.format(now)  // show date time upper right

  if (t >= 0 )
  {
    if (!holidazeEnd.complete)
    {
      tCountDown[xDays].textContent  = Math.floor(t / one_Day);
      tCountDown[xHours].textContent = ('0' + Math.floor((t % one_Day) / one_Hour)).slice(-2);
      tCountDown[xMins].textContent  = ('0' + Math.floor((t % one_Hour) / one_Min)).slice(-2);
      tCountDown[xSecs].textContent  = ('0' + Math.floor((t % one_Min) / one_Sec)).slice(-2);
    }
    // else { nothing to do }
  }
  else // elapsed time !
  {
    if ( holidazeEnd.complete ) // elapsed time of ' holiday ' message
    {
      holidazeEnd =  SetNextHolidayTarget() // searching the next one in the ' holidays ' list
    }
    else  // show ' holiday ' message
    {
      timer_on.classList.add('noDisplay')
      timer_off.classList.remove('noDisplay')
      holidazeEnd.complete  = true;
      holidazeEnd.start = holidazeEnd.ending
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = holidazeEnd.Bcolor
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #554a63;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#currentDateTime {
  text-align: right;
  padding: .2em 1em 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-stretch: expanded
}
.noDisplay {
  display:none !important
}
.timer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.timer h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(96, 87, 151, 0.315);
  padding: .8em 0;
}
.timer h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .3em 0;
}
#countdown {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
  background-color: rgba(96, 87, 151, 0.315);
  min-width: 26em;
}
#countdown div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 5em;
  width: 6em;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
#countdown div:first-child {
  width: 8em;
}
#countdown div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
#countdown div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}
#countdown div span:first-child {
  font-size: 3em;
}
#countdown div span:last-child {
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 1em .2em;
}
```

```html
<p id="currentDateTime"></p>
  
<div id="timer-on" class="timer">
  <h2> .. </h2>
  <div id="countdown">
    <div><span>.</span><span>Days</span></div>
    <div><span>.</span><span>Hours</span></div>
    <div><span>.</span><span>Minutes</span></div>
    <div><span>.</span><span>Seconds</span></div>
  </div>                                
</div>

<div id="timer-off" class="timer noDisplay">
  <h1>!</h1>
</div>
```